# Can the GPU be disabled (turned off) on a laptop?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, overheating, asus-laptop

I have Asus G73-JH laptop with ATI 5870 GPU. It has some serious heating problems. I am running Windows 8. Is it possible to turn off the GPU and use the onboard graphics, like when simply broswing around?

The reason I am asking this is even at minimal load (0%), normal temperature is 105 Celsius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could find, the G73-JH does not have Hybrid graphics, so no, you cannot turn off the GPU

Still, check the BIOS, if theres an option to use integrated graphics, or something of the sort

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To tell you the truth, I can't even watch a movie, without the laptop going off due to overheating. Could you advise me on some other way to take care of this issue. The only solution I see is manual cleaning of vents and heatsink.

Comment: @anirudha Manual cleaning should be done. IF you cannot do it yourself, perhaps you can take it to a service center. For light usage, you should be able to downclock the GPU using  a utility such as RivaTuner or the included overclocking utlilty. do the same for the processor (as a 1st step, try running the laptop in max. battery life mode)

Comment: I ll try the RivaTuner utility. All this was on max battery settings, and the included overclocking utility is a joke. Anyways the servicing time had come, but this is a recurring issue. Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to add, make sure the cooling policy is "active", though I guess the fan should be running at 100% anyways at those temps

Comment: Lol...Obviously I checked that before coming here. It's not even the CPU (they both have different vents). In comparison, CPU is running  like a charm, but GPU cooling is not all that great.